# Heavy DNS issues on Windows 10

Tags: windows, dns, windows-10

I've upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7. Since then the PC looses very often Internet connection. Browser fails with DNS_PROBE error and Windows system log has warning that the requested Domain is not resolvable because of DNS Servers which are not responding.

I've got 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 configured. All other devices have no problems.

When this happens and I try to deactivate or repair the Lan Adapter, it loads forever. Also rebooting takes minutes. So I am forced to power off manually.

After a reboot it works again. For minutes, sometimes hours long.

I did a clean install then, and the problem still appears. I've just installed: Dropbox, Chrome, Nvidia Drivers (installed by Windows Update), Battle.net Launcher.

I am very close to reinstall Windows 7 to proof that it's not about the hardware. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu and there no network issues appears. So it seems to be a bug in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've fixed this issue by myself. The full term of the PC I have is [Studio XPS 8100](http://www.dell.com/support/home/de/de/dedhs1/product-support/servicetag/76K3R4J/drivers?detect=y) of Dell. There are drivers for **Broadcom BCM57780 LOM, v.12.2.2.2** available, which work well in Windows 10.